# public ip camera reading with opencv

Tags: python, opencv, rtsp, ip-camera

I would like to process an public ip camera stream in a simple python application, but I can't get it to work. I am able to connect with the local stream using rtsp, but when I try to caputre the stream in the same fashion via [ipcamlive.com](https://ipcamlive.com/2022camera1) I am not able to open the stream. I am using an Axis camera model M3105-L which streams h264.

This is the code for capturing the stream on my local network. The code actually doesn't matter. Only the url matters.

Theres an code example on how to embed the stream (`<iframe src= "https://g0.ipcamlive.com/player/player.php?alias=2022camera1" width="800px" height="450px" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen> </iframe>`) into your webpage, but I would like to process the stream with opencv as well to eventually do something with motion detection etc.

Any help would be appriciated. Thank you in advance.

```
import cv2
import os

RTSP_URL = 'rtsp://<username>:<password>@<ip-address>/axis-media/media.amp'

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(RTSP_URL, cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)

if not cap.isOpened():
    print('Cannot open RTSP stream')
    exit(-1)

while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('RTSP stream', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Does it work with vlc media player, ffplay and/or mplayer with that public url?

Comment: How exactly do you try to capture from the public ip cam url?

Comment: @Micka Theres an code example on how to embed the stream (```<iframe src= "https://g0.ipcamlive.com/player/player.php?alias=2022camera1" width="800px" height="450px" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen> </iframe>```) into your webpage, but I would like to process the stream with opencv as well to eventually do something with motion detection etc.

Comment: sure, but Does it work with vlc media player, ffplay and/or mplayer with that public url?

Comment: the iframe link probably loads a js based webplayer. try to debug from webbrowser or wireshark, tho find out, what that thing loads in the end

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Is this what u mean? this link runs in vlc player https://s86.ipcamlive.com/streams/56o2amvytgydlpsks/stream.m3u8

Comment: good! that is a HLS stream. ffmpeg/ffplay/VLC can read that. put that URL into a VideoCapture() and it will work.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thank you, it worked! I eventually decided to restream the rtsp stream after I processed it with opencv myself trough a server, since I only have to run the application locally. You gave me a better understanding of what was happening.